# If $x\not\equiv\pm y ($mod$n)$ but $x^2 \equiv y^2($mod $n)$, why is gcd$(x-y, n)$ not equal to $1$ or $n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, sieve-theory

Let's say I have an integer $n$ and two integers $y$ and $x$ such that

$x\not\equiv\pm y ($mod$n)$ but $x^2 \equiv y^2($mod $n)$

This would of course imply that $(x-y)(x+y) \equiv 0 ($mod $n)$.

Why, then, are the greatest common divisors $(x-y, n)$ and $(x+y,n)$ not equal to $1$ or $n$ ?

I have to explain to some people this, which is the essence of the Quadratic Sieve Method, and I'm certain the Chinese Remainder Theorem will be useful in explaining it here, but I need someone to help me explain why that statement is true.

Comment: What about $x=25,y=5,n=50$? $gcd(x-y,n)=10$ is not prime.

Comment: I see. Let's say n is odd (I changed it). Can you find a counterexample now?

Comment: Then what about $x=49,y=7,n=147$? $gcd(x-y,n)=21$ is not prime.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.  I realize now that I should change it altogether so that the gcd is any factor (not necessarily prime) and n may be odd or even.

Comment: But then that would be trivial because $gcd(m,n)$ is obviously a factor of $n$ no matter what $m$ is.

Comment: But let's say the gcd were not $1$ or $n$ (trivial factors).  Then you would have to know what $m$ was to get a non-trivial factor of $n$.

Comment: Why are such an $x$ and $y$ described in the question correct for finding such an $m$ that when you take gcd$(m,n)$, you should get something other than $n$ or 1 ?  <-- is that a better way to ask it? I think that is correct.

Comment: Question has been changed to better reflect what I mean.. Thank you for helping me understand it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show $gcd(x-y,n)\neq n$, we assume the opposite first for the sake of contradiction, then $n|x-y$ contradicting $x\not\equiv y\pmod{n}$.

To show $gcd(x+y,n)\neq n$, we assume the opposite first then $n|x+y$ contradicting $x\not\equiv -y\pmod{n}$.

To show $gcd(x-y,n)\neq1$, we assume the opposite, then since $x^2-y^2$ is a multiple of $n$ and $x-y,n$ are coprime, $n|x+y$ contradicting $x\not\equiv -y\pmod{n}$.

To show $gcd(x+y,n)\neq1$, we assume the opposite, then since $x^2-y^2$ is a multiple of $n$ and $x+y,n$ are coprime, $n|x-y$ contradicting $x\not\equiv y\pmod{n}$.

Comment: Hi @cr001 under then condition given above how can we conclude that $n=gcd(x-y,n)*gcd(x+y,n)$?